# how to compile react jsx file to js file

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm new to react js and I use create-react-app npm package for creating react project.
When I run `npm start` command in terminal and view developer console of browser error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` shown in console. It show jsx files doesn't compile to js files.

one of my javascript files code is

```
class ProductsList extends React.Component{
    render(){
       return (
         <div class="">
         Hello
         </div>
       );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <ProductsList/>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Answer (score -3):

Files with the `.jsx` extension are already JavaScript files. That should be the same thing as `.js` files. The use of `jsx` is just to emphasize the file contains code written using JSX syntactic sugar.

Generating a project with `create-react-app` should already come with webpack set up by default. Your code should already be transpiled from ES6 to ES5. There should be no issues.

One thing I noticed in your code is that you use `class` as a prop do div. By default, in React, you have to use `className` instead.

```
<div className="some-class">
  Hello
</div>
```

Comment: [Babel's online transpiler, configured to take JSX for React, and turn it into vanilla JS](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?presets=react&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwKYBt1wBQEpEDeAUIogE6pQhlIA8AJjAG4B8AEhlogO5xnr0AhLQD0jVgG4iAXyJA) - the output could be sent to a browser, along with React js module.

Comment: To clarify your comment *"Files with the .jsx extension are already JavaScript files.": I wouldn't say it that way, especially in answer to a novice question. Specifically, the file won't run as-is in a browser. It has to be "transpiled" to ordinary JS (as you mention, part of the webpack bundling process). The link I've given above is useful to see what that "JSX syntactic sugar" gets turned into, before the webpack bundle is sent to a browser. [React without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html) may also be useful to someone who wishes to understand exactly what is going on.